# removing patches in transparent parametric 3D plot

Tags: plotting

When I plot a 3d sphere using `ParametricPlot3D` and decreases the opacity there some triangular shaped patches come. How can I remove these pathces?   Following is my code for parametric plot 3d sphere.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
  Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 
  2 π}, {θ, -π, π}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[.5]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the number of plotpoints:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, 
{ϕ, 0,  2 π}, {θ, -π, π},  
PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[.5]}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

looks nice in my notebook.